# Converting stream in C# to ofstream in C++

Tags: c#, c++, stream, ofstream

We are developing a mobile application with xamarin. There is also c++ library which is used in our solution. Currently everthing is going on with a file. C# project writes values in a file and c++ project read the file as ofstream.

As it is android, we do not want to save something on the device because of efficency and permission.

Is it possible to convert stream object to ofstream object? I checked some sample and unfortunately they've always used a temporar file for conversion. My question is that there is another way to do that instead of writing in a file?

Comment: I assume you mean `ifstream` since C++ is *reading*. Anyway, a stream is merely some pointers, it doesn't contain the file. You can do the reading and send around strings instead.

Comment: the type is actually basic_ofstream<char> so giving a string is a good Idea. I'll look for it. Thank you